# Do we need to restore civicrm_cache in upgrades?

Tags: cache

when we upgrade to newer versions of civicrm, do we need to restore records from the  civicrm_cache in the old version to the new one? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, civi clears cache on purpose during upgrade.

I'm assuming you're having some cache problem. Such problems are almost always caused by file system permissions. Check the cache folder is writable by the web server unix user (e.g. apache, wwwrun, etc)